# How to "duplicate" template parameter pack expansion?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, c++17

Consider this code:

```
template < size_t... Indices >
void something(std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
{
  // how to obtain the following call where N is sizeof...(Indices)?
  // foo(f(0),g(0),f(1),g(1),...,f(N-1),g(N-1));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to answering a question like:

```
// how to obtain the following call where N is sizeof...(Indices)?
// foo(f(0),g(0),f(1),g(1),...,f(N-1),g(N-1));
```

is to formulate how to actually generate such a pack expansion. We have `2N` arguments, which would like:

```
+=====+======+
| idx | expr |
+-----+------+
|  0  | f(0) |
|  1  | g(0) |
|  2  | f(1) |
|  3  | g(1) |
|   ....
+=====+======+
```

In C++17, we can write such an expression with `if constexpr`:

```
template <size_t I>
auto expr() {
    if constexpr (I % 2 == 0) { 
        // even indices are fs
        return f(I / 2);
    } else {
        // odds are gs
        return g(I / 2);
    }
}
```

Which can even be a lambda that takes an `integral_constant` as an argument. So we really just need to turn our `N` arguments into `2N` arguments, which is just a matter of adding more indices:

```
template <auto V>
using constant = std::integral_constant<decltype(V), V>;

template < size_t... Indices >
void something(std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    auto expr = [](auto I) {
        if constexpr (I % 2 == 0) {
            return f(I / 2);
        } else {
            return g(I / 2);
        }
    }

    return foo(
        expr(constant<Indices>{})...,                     // 0, ..., N-1
        expr(constant<Indices + sizeof...(Indices)>{})... // N, ..., 2N-1
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best I can imagine is the use of `std::tuple_cat` and `std::make_pair` to make a `std::tuple` of arguments of `foo()`.

Unfortunately I know how to do it only with an helper function to call `foo()`

```
template <typename T, std::size_t... I>
void somethingH (T const & t, std::index_sequence<I...> const &)
 { foo(std::get<I>(t)...); }

template <std::size_t... I>
void something (std::index_sequence<I...> const &)
 {
   somethingH(std::tuple_cat(std::make_pair(f(I), g(I))...),
              std::make_index_sequence<(sizeof...(I) << 1)>{});
 }
```

Using `std::apply`, available only starting from C++17, you can use a lambda function to select the correct `foo` (as SirGuy suggested; thanks!) and avoid the helper function

```
template <std::size_t... I>
void something (std::index_sequence<I...> const &)
 {
   std::apply([](auto && ... as)
                 { return foo(std::forward<decltype(as)>(as)...); },
              std::tuple_cat(std::make_pair(f(I), g(I))...));
 }
```

The following is a full C++17 working example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

int f (std::size_t n)
 { return n; }

int g (std::size_t n)
 { return -n; }

template <typename ... Args>
void foo (Args ... as)
 { (std::cout << ... << as) << std::endl; }

template <std::size_t... I>
void something (std::index_sequence<I...> const &)
 {
   std::apply([](auto && ... as)
                 { return foo(std::forward<decltype(as)>(as)...); },
              std::tuple_cat(std::make_pair(f(I), g(I))...));
 }

int main()
 {
   something(std::make_index_sequence<7U>{});
 }
```

Comment: With the `std::apply` version, why not just make a lambda instead of a function called `getCorrectFoo`? `std::apply([](auto && ... args) { return foo(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);}, t);`

Comment: @SirGuy - because I'm not used to lambda functions as you :( . Very nice improvement; thanks!